# mapreduce job doesn't get executed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have a simple MapReduce job that I have borrowed from the [avro website](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/mr.html) with some minor modification (I removed the reducer). It basically takes a simple avro file as input. Here is the schema of the avro file

avro schema:

```
 {
"type": "record",
"name": "User",
"fields": [
{"name": "name", "type": "string"},
{"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"},
{"name":"favorite_color", "type": "string"}
]
}
```

and here are my mapreduce job (the mapper and the main function):

```
public class ColorCountMapper extends Mapper<AvroKey<User>, NullWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

@Override
public void map(AvroKey<User> key, NullWritable value, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  CharSequence color = key.datum().getFavoriteColor();
  if (color == null) {
    color = "none";
  }
  context.write(new Text(color.toString()), new IntWritable(1));
}
```

}

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "TestColor");
    job.setJarByClass(runClass.class);
    job.setJobName("Color Count");

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("in"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

    job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ColorCountMapper.class);
    AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, User.getClassSchema());
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


    boolean r = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.out.println(r);  
}
```

When I run the program it return false and doesn't succeed. I can't figure out the problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the value type of the Mapper as ***NullWritable***. Then in the main/driver you have set the Map-output value class as ***IntWritable***. Your value type in the Mapper and the main/driver should be the same. Modify your program accordingly. Accept my the answer if you have the solution.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?